# compute with R commands?

Tags: r

how in Rstudio, I can compute the below command?.

[image]

Comment: thank you, Akrun. since im new in stats and R, can you please explain why we used (2:101)?

Comment: `:` returns the sequence of values from `2` to `101`  it is 2 to 101 because your `n` starts from 1 to 100 whereas the denominator is `n+1`

Answer (score 2):

We may use vectorized option in `R`

```
out <- sum((3^(1:100))/(factorial(2:101)))
out
[1] 5.361846
```

checking with a `for` loop

```
out2 <- 0
for(n in 1:100) out2 <- sum(out2, 3^n/factorial(n + 1))
out2
[1] 5.361846
```

---

Similarly, we can create the formula for the ones showed in the update

```
sum(((2^(5:15))/((5:15)^2))  + (((5:15)^4)/(4^(5:15))))
[1] 350.4776
sum(((1:11) * (5^(0:10)))/(14^(1:11)))
[1] 0.1728227
prod((2 * (2:22)) + (2/sqrt(2:22)))
[1] 7.117167e+27
```

Answer (score 0):

vectorized option stated above is probably the most efficient way to do it.

If you want to see it in closer format to your formula for readability because you are new (as you pointed) you can do the following:

```
my_sum = 0
for(n in 1:100) {
    my_sum = my_sum + 3^n / factorial(n+1) 
}
```

Comment: This isn't fundamentally different from akrun's `for` loop option

Comment: to be fair it is not "fundamentally" different from akrun's vectorized solution either (which is the way to go anyways). given that shahzad is new to R `<-` operator may not be clear to them and they may not be familiar with writing single line for loops. and instead of using sum, writing out formula more clear may help. Thats what I thought at least, but I might be wrong.